# How to limit data being grabbed in python beautifulsoup in a page that refreshes every few seconds

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to grab some data. The problem I am facing is that the page refreshes every few seconds. I wanted to limit the data grabs based on the latest block only and refresh the scan and hopefully catch up with the next succeeding block. Any idea will be very helpful.

Goal #1 - Continuity with grabbed blocks

Goal #2 - Eliminate Duplicates

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep
import re, requests

trim = re.compile(r'[^\d,.]+')

url = "https://bscscan.com/txs?a=0x10ed43c718714eb63d5aa57b78b54704e256024e&ps=100&p=1"
baseurl = 'https://bscscan.com/tx/'
header = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"}
scans = 0

while True:
    scans += 1
    reqtxsInternal = requests.get(url,header, timeout=2)
    souptxsInternal = BeautifulSoup(reqtxsInternal.content, 'html.parser')
    blocktxsInternal = souptxsInternal.findAll('table')[0].findAll('tr')

    for row in blocktxsInternal[1:]:
        txnhash = row.find_all('td')[1].text[0:]
        txnhashdetails = txnhash.strip()
        block = row.find_all('td')[3].text[0:]
        value = row.find_all('td')[9].text[0:]
        amount = trim.sub('', value).replace(",", "")
        transval = float(amount)
        
        if float(transval) >= 1:
            print ("Doing something with the data -> " + str(block) + "   " + str(transval))
        else:
            pass
    print (" -> Whole Page Scanned: ", scans)
sleep(1)
```

Current Output: #-- will be different when you run the script

```
Doing something with the data -> 10186993   1.233071907624764
Doing something with the data -> 10186993   4.689434542638692
Doing something with the data -> 10186993   27.97137792744322   #-- grab only until here and reload the scan
Doing something with the data -> 10186992   9.0
Doing something with the data -> 10186991   2.98
Doing something with the data -> 10186991   1.0
 -> Whole Page Scanned:  1
Doing something with the data -> 10186994   1.026868093169767
Doing something with the data -> 10186994   4.0
Doing something with the data -> 10186994   4.55582682
Doing something with the data -> 10186994   8.184713205161088
Doing something with the data -> 10186993   1.233071907624764
Doing something with the data -> 10186993   4.689434542638692
Doing something with the data -> 10186993   27.97137792744322
Doing something with the data -> 10186992   9.0
 -> Whole Page Scanned:  2
```

Wanted Output:

```
Doing something with the data -> 10186993   1.233071907624764
Doing something with the data -> 10186993   4.689434542638692
Doing something with the data -> 10186993   27.97137792744322
 -> Whole Page Scanned:  1
Doing something with the data -> 10186994   1.026868093169767
Doing something with the data -> 10186994   4.0
Doing something with the data -> 10186994   4.55582682
Doing something with the data -> 10186994   8.184713205161088
 -> Whole Page Scanned:  2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I utilized `Pandas` here since it uses beautifulsoup under the hood anyway, but since it's a table, I let pandas parse it. Then it's easy to manipulate the table.

So what it looks like is you only want the latest/max `"Block"` then return any values greater than or equal to 1. Does this give you what you want?

```
import pandas as pd
from time import sleep
import requests

url = "https://bscscan.com/txs?a=0x10ed43c718714eb63d5aa57b78b54704e256024e&ps=100&p=1"
baseurl = 'https://bscscan.com/tx/'
header = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"}
scans = 0

while True:
    scans += 1
    reqtxsInternal = requests.get(url,header, timeout=2)
    df = pd.read_html(reqtxsInternal.text)[0]
    df = df[df['Block'] == max(df['Block'])]
    df['Value'] = df['Value'].str.extract('(^\d*.*\d+)')
    df = df[df['Value'].astype(float) >= 1]
    
    print (df[['Block','Value']])
    print (" -> Whole Page Scanned: ", scans)
sleep(1)
```

Your other option is just have it check to see if the current `'block'` is greater than the previous. Then add that logic to only print if it is:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep
import re, requests

trim = re.compile(r'[^\d,.]+')

url = "https://bscscan.com/txs?a=0x10ed43c718714eb63d5aa57b78b54704e256024e&ps=100&p=1"
baseurl = 'https://bscscan.com/tx/'
header = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"}
scans = 0
previous_block = 0
while True:
    scans += 1
    reqtxsInternal = requests.get(url,header, timeout=2)
    souptxsInternal = BeautifulSoup(reqtxsInternal.content, 'html.parser')
    blocktxsInternal = souptxsInternal.findAll('table')[0].findAll('tr')

    for row in blocktxsInternal[1:]:
        txnhash = row.find_all('td')[1].text[0:]
        txnhashdetails = txnhash.strip()
        block = row.find_all('td')[3].text[0:]
        if float(block) > float(previous_block):
            previous_block = block
        value = row.find_all('td')[9].text[0:]
        amount = trim.sub('', value).replace(",", "")
        transval = float(amount)
        
        if float(transval) >= 1 and block == previous_block:
            print ("Doing something with the data -> " + str(block) + "   " + str(transval))
        else:
            pass
    print (" -> Whole Page Scanned: ", scans)
sleep(1)
```

Comment: I think, for now I will use the second option. I have noticed though that it cannot cope up with all of the latest blocks in succession but it works.

Comment: What do you mean with "cannot cope up with all of the latest blocks in succession"?

Comment: I mean I expected it to miss some blocks. I tried running the script for 3 minutes and observe the result. For example I started with block 1000101, it reads succeeding blocks and miss some like 1000101, 1000102, 1000103, 1000105, 1000106, 1000109 and so on.

Comment: ah ya. Well it may skip those because all the values for that block may be less than 1. Remember it's only showing the ones that are >= 1 (I thought that's what you wanted??)

Comment: Also, do you not want it repeat/show duplicates? I can fix that. I was just reworking the code you provided...

Comment: I tried to see the results by changing some values. I will create another question and hope you can help out.

Answer (score 2):

The continuity works only if the `block` number is increasing/decreasing.

Since the data is changing with every refresh, I would suggest to Collect the data nedeed first, then Deduplicate and do the something you want.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep
import re, requests

trim = re.compile(r'[^\d,.]+')

url = "https://bscscan.com/txs?a=0x10ed43c718714eb63d5aa57b78b54704e256024e&ps=100&p=1"
baseurl = 'https://bscscan.com/tx/'
header = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"}
scans = 0

all_data = set()
prev_block = 0
while True:
    scans += 1
    reqtxsInternal = requests.get(url,header, timeout=2)
    souptxsInternal = BeautifulSoup(reqtxsInternal.content, 'html.parser')
    blocktxsInternal = souptxsInternal.findAll('table')[0].findAll('tr')
    
    for row in blocktxsInternal[1:]:
        txnhash = row.find_all('td')[1].text[0:]
        txnhashdetails = txnhash.strip()
        block = int(row.find_all('td')[3].text[0:])
        value = row.find_all('td')[9].text[0:]
        amount = trim.sub('', value).replace(",", "")
        transval = float(amount)
        
        if (prev_block != 0) and (block < prev_block):
            # print(block, prev_block)
            continue
        else:
            prev_block = block

        if (block >= prev_block) and (transval >= 1):
            # print(block, prev_block)
            print("Do something with the data -> " + str(block) + " " + str(transval))
            
            # collect the data
            all_data.add((block, transval))
        else:
            pass
        
    print (" -> Whole Page Scanned: ", scans)
    sleep(1)
                
        
# do something with the data
print('Do something with this collected data:', all_data)
```

Comment: This works also. It miss some blocks after running it for a few minutes to observe the result. I will make some further testing tomorrow.

Comment: Is there a way not to read same blocks again? After running the script for few minutes, it reads duplicate blocks mostly 2 times or 3 times.